# Return value to another class/object without added a relation between them C#

Tags: c#, callback

I having some classes related like the following domain drawing:

[image: MyClass has the responsibility of both classes]

The Requestcontroller is running a loop in a ThreadPool, which on received messages will handle them and call some methods in FooClass, which then should throw exceptions if anything goes wrong.

In example (in some way pseudo-code):

```
class RequestController
{
    private FooClass fooClass;

    public RequestController(ref FooClass fooClass)
    {
        this.fooClass = fooClass;
    }

    void OnResponseReceived()
    {
        try
        {
            this.fooClass.ProcessingRequest("id", "requestType", 13);
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.Fail(ex.Message);
        }
    }
}


class FooClass
{
    private object myObj;
    [...]

    public void ProcessingRequest(string id, string type, int count)
    {
        try
        {
            myObj.MethodAsync(id, type, RequestFailedCB, myObj);
            //This method throws an Exception, that I want to be handled by RequestController class based on the Exception
        }
        catch(Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

So, my problem is that the Async method (MethodAsync in FooClass) will fail, and throw an Exception in FooClass, but it's giving me "Unhandle Exception". What I want is that the Requestcontroller is calling the method of FooClass, and if the async method that has been invoked in the FooClass.ProcessingRequest fails and throws an exception, which my RequestController should react on, and sending a message further on in the system, that there has been an error in the response received.

Would it be an idea to make the ProcessingRequest as and Callback method, or are there any better way to solve this purpose???

EDIT:
@KC-NH without posting pages of complex code, I'll try to get closer to the point.
As commented I forgot to mention that the project i .net 4 target. And the example posted in the FooClass method, is actually calling a .BeginTransfer of the UCMA 4 api, which I want to catch if it fails, and let the RequestController send a message about the failure further on in the system. The .BeginTransfer method returns IAsyncResult, and needs a Callback as one of the parameters.
The exception that the system throws, is inside this CB, but if I try to throw that exception from the Callback, I'm getting "Unhandled Exception", probably cuz the callback doesn't know where to throw that exception??

Comment: Based on the names, I suspect the problem is in MethodAsync and RequestFailedCB. Can you post the code for those?

Comment: @KC-NH I see you have enough rep to comment now! This is a good comment by the way :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[.NET 4.5 specific solution]

You should always `await` async calls. `await` will rethrow exceptions as expected. This should correct your problem:

```
class RequestController
{
  private FooClass fooClass;

  public RequestController(ref FooClass fooClass)
  {
    this.fooClass = fooClass;
  }

  public async void OnResponseReceived()
  {
    try
    {
      await fooClass.ProcessingRequest();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
      System.Diagnostics.Debug.Fail(ex.Message);
    }
  }
}

public class FooClass
{
  private object myObj;

  public async Task ProcessingRequest()
  {
    await myObj.MethodAsync(id, type, RequestFailedCB, myObj);
  }
}
```

Comment: Forgot to say that my target framework is .net 4. If I ain't wrong, Async keywords is only included in .net 4.5 and upwards?

Comment: OK, sorry, I'm too used to it ;) Could you post the general structure of your implementation of MethodAsync?

Comment: Updated the main post to (hopefully) explain it some more :)

Answer (score 0):

I spoke with one of my colleagues today. He suggested that I used an EventHandler, to raise an event on exception catched in the callback method inside my FooClass. So the solution looks like this:

1. FooClass RequestFailedCB throws an exception
2. In RequestFailedCB the exception gets catched, and raising a ErrorEvent on my EventHandler.
3. The RequestController now gets information, that an event has been raised.
4. The RequestController will handle the error throw by the event, based on EventArgs and sender object, and can now send that error further on in the system.

Problem solved :) Thanks for all inputs.

Comment: Based on your post update, I was going to suggest to use a `Task` wrapper (using .NET 4.0 TPL Async). Wrapping an APM call with a `Task` makes it easy to manage exceptions. Let me know if you still want some details.